# Как сделать загрузочную флешку?

Tags: linux, debian, live-usb

Флешка в ext3 (debian, Download a small installation image). Делал так

```
dd if=/home/path of=/dev/sdb1.
```

Вставляю, не грузится!

Comment: @ХэшКод ok, буду знать

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584247/201026

Answer (score 2):

[unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) - это свободная кроссплатформенная утилита для создания Live USB системы из ISO-образа CD/DVD диска с Linux/BSD.