# Загрузочная флешка для чтения и записи

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

**OS**: Xubuntu 16.04.1

**Flash card**: SanDisk Cruser Facet 16GB

**Исходный образ**: xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

---

Сначала я попробовал с помощью Startup Disk Creator (`usb-creator-gtk`) — создаётся загрузочная флешка только для чтения.

Далее я попробовал с помощью `cp` — создаётся загрузочная флешка только для чтения.

Далее я попробовал с помощью `dd` — создаётся загрузочная флешка только для чтения.

---

**Как сделать загрузочную флешку из образа xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso на Xubuntu 16.04.1, чтобы в ней можно было создавать директории и копировать в эти директории файлы?**

Это пробовал:

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
```

---

Когда я делал загрузочной эту же флешку на Ubuntu 14.04 с помощью того же Startup Disk Creator, то всё отлично работало.

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе, чего **именно** вы хотите добиться.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, уточнил.

Comment: http://www.lubuntu.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=237 - оно?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/500523/178988

Comment: Вопрос решился с помощью [UNetbootin](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584247/201026) ...

Comment: @donRumata, а на форуме по ссылке говорится про grub legacy или про grub 2?

Comment: @Qwertiy, учитывая старость поста - не имеет особого смысла, потому что много что могло поменяться и надо всё равно тестировать с текущей версией iso и grub.

Comment: @donRumata, мне на первый взгляд показалось, что там универсальный вариант расписан. Но внимательно не читал. Или с тех пор есть кардинальные изменения?

Comment: @Qwertiy, когда ловишь баг на скрипте в понедельник утром, который в пятницу вечером был отлажен и оттестирован и к нему точно никто не прикасался - начинаешь параноить по любой фигне. По идее - всё должно работать и так, но как в том пошлом анекдоте "есть, Петька, нюанс".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете осуществить это с помощью [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

> Обязательно добавьте репозиторий: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa`; иначе установиться не самая новая версия, которая может работать некорректно.

[image: UNetbootin on Xubuntu]

В программе можно выбрать два варианта получения ISO-образа:

- выбрать из выпадающего списка дистрибутив и она сама его скачает;
- выбрать уже скачанный дистрибутив.

Перед создании загрузочной флешки её лучше **полностью отформатировать** в **FAT32**.

---

[Для продвинутых пользователей.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584256/201026)

Comment: Я пробовал через UNetbootin, сейчас как раз пробую повторно.

Comment: Первый раз я не добавлял, видимо, репозиторий.

Comment: Хм.. А "Ubuntu only" с минтом как, подойдёт?

Answer (score 3):

> Как сделать загрузочную флешку из образа xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso на Xubuntu 16.04.1, чтобы в ней можно было создавать директории и копировать в эти директории файлы?

ввиду того, что внутри этого файла файлы хранятся в файловой системе [iso9660](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660), изменять их «на лету» не получится: эта файловая система разработана именно как «только для чтения».

поэтому надо:

1. либо создать на разделе этого блочного устройства «обычную» файловую систему (подойдёт даже какой-нибудь fat), скопировать туда упомянутый iso-файл, и обеспечить загрузку системы из этого файла (т.е., сделать т.н. multiboot). [пример для загрузчика grub](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive).

   вы сможете создавать/изменять файлы/каталоги «рядом» с этим iso-файлом (но, конечно, не «внутри» него).
2. либо установить систему полноценно на блочное устройство. например, запишите этот iso-файл на dvd или ещё одно блочное устройство, загрузитесь с него, и [установите систему на целевое блочное устройство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/500530/178576).

   впоследствии, загрузившись с этого блочного устройства (или примонтировав раздел с него в рабочей системе), вы сможете создавать/изменять любые файлы/каталоги.

Answer (score 0):

**Роман, я правильно вас понял? Вам нужен загрузочный флеш накопитель, с возможностью сохранения настроек текущего сеанса, и возможность установки дистрибутива на компьютер?**

Для этого вам нужно включить "persistence", способность сохранять файлы и изменения во время сеанса.

1. Запишите образ на USB накопитель утилитой dd - в Linux, или win32diskimager - в Windows.
2. Загрузитесь с USB накопителя
3. Создайте раздел на на USB накопителе в неиспользуемом пространстве, метка раздела persistence, это обязательно.
4. Монтируем раздел

   mkdir /mnt/usb

   mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb
5. echo "/ union" >> /mnt/usb/persistence.conf
6. umount /mnt/usb
7. Готово.
8. Теперь при загрузке с USB накопителя нажмите на клавишу tab. Это позволит вам изменить параметры загрузки. Добавьте слово “persistence” в конце строки параметров загрузки каждый раз, когда вы хотите смонтировать ваше persistent устройство.

Comment: Вопрос [решился](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584247/201026).

Comment: Думаю, надо добавить ещё пару шагов, чтобы не надо было каждый раз загрузку с опциями вызывать?

Comment: Согласен, можно просто добавить дополнительный пункт в меню grub2, не знаю как в ubuntu, сам пользуюсь kali. В ней такой пункт уже есть.

Comment: Раньше в ubuntu была утилита usb-creator-gtk, выполняет те же функции http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/usb-creator-gtk, сейчас как обстоят дела не в курсе, если осталась, можете использовать её.